More fine-grained syntax highlighting in VS Code for JavaScript

I am trying to highlit the words http, url req, res, but I cannot get it to work.
I have installed 3 different extensions: ESLint, Javascript Snippet, Babel JavaScript but none of them highlit those parts in my code. I am working with node.js.

That's not how syntax highlighting works and it isn't intellisense. You aren't going to be able to fix that with a plugin like the ones you listed, but you may be able to fix it by using a more discriminating colorscheme.

None of the extensions you listed provide syntax highlighting?

Using the theme "Dark high contrast" and it colors imports and variable names (to be fair, it colors everything). So, it's just a matter of finding a theme that does so, or creating one yourself.
